# Copy Background color from Master sheet to worksheet - not the contents

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wonder if anyone can help, I'm a noob when it comes to excel. I have to create a speadsheet which will be used in Datacenter management and hardware tracking, so what I've done is created a master worksheet and a sheet per rack, what I need to achieve is when a cell on master sheet is filled with a background color (grey) it then changes the color on the corresponding worksheet. Not sure how much sense that makes :)

Master B2:B25 to worksheet 1 B4:B27.. Master D2:D25 to worksheet 2 B4:B27.. Master E2:E25 to worksheet 3 B4:B27..etc

I can't use copy because it copies the contents of the cell, which I won't want, only the background color.

Comment: copying & using Paste Special has an abundance of options, one of which is Formats. Not sure how else you could do this short of some VBA code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA doesn't have a *change of color event* that can be captured in order to make it fully automatic.

I decide to make it *on double click*. You double click a cell and the the color is copied to the corresponding cell in another worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    total_sheets = wkb.Worksheets.Count
    aff_row = Target.Row
    aff_column = Target.Column
    sheet_used = (aff_column / 2) + 2
    If aff_column > 1 Then
        If Int(sheet_used) = sheet_used Then
            If sheet_used <= total_sheets Then
                wkb.Sheets(sheet_used).Cells(aff_row + 2, 2).Interior.Color = Target.Interior.Color
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Open macros /VBA double click on the left column *Sheet2*, paste the code on the right side

When you change the color of a cell, double click it and it will change in this way:

Sheet2 ColumnB -> Sheet3 ColumnB

Sheet2 ColumnD -> Sheet4 ColumnB

Sheet2 ColumnF -> Sheet5 ColumnB

Always 2 rows below the original row.

Comment: This kinda sounds along the lines of what I need, I can get the users to double click on the cell to be copied, but will this code copy the whole column rather than individual cells?

Comment: @NorrinRad It will copy the individual cell where the double click has been done.

Comment: The columns move along the master worksheet, which incidentally is sheet 2, sheet 1 is summary, so when sheet 2 column B is altered it should reflect in Sheet 3 column b and then sheet 2 column D it should be amended to column sheet 4 column B ..gradually working its way along sheet 2 (master sheet).. hope this makes sense thanks.

Comment: @NorrinRad I changed the code to work on *Sheet2* and to use the appropiate columns.

Answer (score 0):

As you call yourself a noob I'll get you started along the right tracks...

1. Copy cell with original style: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
2. Select destination cell and paste special: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
3. Select formats option to paste only formats of copied cell: <kbd>t</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you select all worksheets (hold shift key and click on every tab) then you can format all of them simultaneously - any change you make to the source sheet will be mirrored in the rest. But that only really makes sense if you're just talking about initial setup of your sheet.

If you want changes like this to happen more regularly and automatically across the workbook's lifetime, this can only be solved using VBA (*Visual Basic for Applications*, which is embedded in most modern versions of Office as standard). In that case you would need to add some code against the Worksheet_Change() event:

1. Remember the background colour of your current selection

   `Dim myColor As Integer
   myColor = Selection.Interior.ColorIndex`
2. Select the new area to apply the colour to; this should select your current range on all visible worksheets.

   `Worksheets.Select`
3. Apply your original background colour to your new selection

   `Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = myColor`
4. Re-select only the tab you were originally working on. (I'm assuming your Master tab is the first sheet)

   `Worksheets(1).Select`

**NB:** without any modifications this code mirrors ALL colour changes from ALL sheets to ALL others whenever ANY cell is changed, which is overkill. The solution could be made much more efficient as needed.